# Monotouch.Dialog bug on new update

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, monotouch.dialog

I used to have the following code:

```cs
var root = new RootElement ("Tasks"){
    new Section ("Process Type"){
        new RootElement ("Process", new RadioGroup ("processtype", 0)){
            new Section (){
                guarantor,dependent, volunteer // all these are Elements    
            }
        }
    }       
};
```

Now, I update `Monotouch SDK`, `Xcode 5`, etc... and when I try to build the project I get an error on the following line:

```cs
new RootElement ("Process", new RadioGroup ("processtype", 0)){
```

with the following error:

```
HumanResources/HumanPendingRequests.cs(18,18): Error CS0121: The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: `MonoTouch.Dialog.Section.Add(MonoTouch.Dialog.Element)' and `MonoTouch.Dialog.Section.Add(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<MonoTouch.Dialog.Element>)' (CS0121)
```

Any clue on how to fix it and why is now showing that error?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's strange, but easy to fix. Force a cast to the type you meant, and the `c#` compiler will find the right overload.

```cs
var root = new RootElement ("Tasks"){
    new Section ("Process Type"){
        (MonoTouch.Dialog.Element)new RootElement ("Process", new RadioGroup ("processtype", 0)){
            new Section (){
                guarantor,dependent, volunteer // all these are Elements    
            }
        }
    }       
};
```